# Different types of resize method not working?

Tags: opencv, interpolation

i'm using opencv 3.4. I have tried different resize method "LINEAR,CUBIC, LANCSOZ4", but when i save the image i get always the same result. I save the image in .png.

I have tried to use the resize function with different interpolation method

```
resize(image, image1, Size(224, 224), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LANCZOS4);
resize(image, image2, Size(224, 224), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
resize(image, image3, Size(224, 224), 0, 0, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
```

I was expected different results for different interpolation methods.

Comment: Can't confirm on Windows 10, OpenCV 3.4.0, VIsual Studio 2017. For some small color image `image`, all three `imageX` have different values for a lot of pixels. Since you're mentioning saving: Do you possibly overwrite your output images by accident, like copy-pasting something like `cv::imwrite("image1.png", image1)` and forgetting to change both information? How do your `imageX` look like when you inspect them at runtime?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i'am on Linux. I don't think because i have also tried to run the code in different run with different interpolation methods